# Laravel 4.2 attempt to make checkout HTTPS leads to NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, ssl, laravel-4, https, laravel-routing

I've been trying to make my checkout HTTPS ready, I've installed the SSL certificate and have been attempting to force the HTTPS. However upon every possible attempt an NotFoundHttpException error.

I've tried this two ways. First I tried it only when the information has been submitted.

```
Route::post('billing', ['https', function(){
```

When that didn't work I attempted to begin the forced https right at the checkout page.

```
Route::get('/checkout',['https', 'uses' => 'CartController@checkout']);
```

Even the recommended way via Laravel's official site doesn't work.

```
Route::get('foo', array('https', function()
{
return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

I'm completely and utterly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::secure(URL::route('checkout.validate',[],false)) ,'id' => 'checkout-form', 'method' => 'post' )) }}


Route::post('validate', array('https' => true,'as' => 'checkout.validate', 'uses' => 'Vendor\Controllers\CheckoutController@validate'));
```